# Can I save a mass email message on the record?

Tags: email, massemailmessage

**Problem:** Our users make extensive use of Salesforce's native Mass Email functionality, but when a mass email is sent out, SF records it as a Task and not as an email (see screenshot.) This poses a problem when our users are interested in reviewing the email that was sent out.

**Question:** Is there anyway to preserve the actual email that went out? Or at least a copy of the email template that was used at the time?

[image: Picture of a Mass Email recorded as a task]

Comment: What third party tool are you looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike, this is a very common issue and one that I have yet to solve gracefully.

The closest I have been is to make a custom button or link that takes the name out of the subject and links through to the mass email template.  The issue with this is if there are mass emails with the same name, it will possibly pick up the wrong one.

If your team is using mass email so much, it is probably worth looking into a third party tool.  This is not a strength of Salesforce.

Comment: We are starting to use a 3rd party tool more, but are still in the early stages of rolling it out.